# Show that the tranformation $ w = z + \frac{1}{z}$ transform r = constant in the z plane into a family of ellipses in the w plane.

Tags: complex-analysis, conformal-geometry

Here we have,

$$w = z + \frac{1}{z}$$

$$\therefore u + iv = x + iy + \frac{1}{x + iy}$$

On solving and comparing the real and imaginary parts we get,

$$ u = x(1 + \frac{1}{x^2 + y^2})$$ and

$$ v = y(1 - \frac{1}{x^2 + y^2})$$

What's next from here?

Comment: **Hint.** Well, what's $x^2+y^2$ equal to?

Comment: Also, I'm not sure I see where you got your expressions for $u$ and $v$...can you show that work? For instance, if $x = -1$ and $y = 0$.

Comment: rationalized the inverse z stuff and and compared the real parts to get u and imaginary parts to get v

Comment: But if $z = -1$, then $x = -1$ and $y = 0$. But then $w = -1 + \frac{1}{-1} = -2$, but $u = 1 + \frac{1}{(-1)^2+0^2} = 2$?

Comment: i missed x and y there, sorry for that typo @BrianTung

Comment: OK, square $u$ and $v$. Then compare with $x^2+y^2 = \;$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $ z=x+iy$ and $w=u+iv$. Then, $w=z+\frac1z$ becomes

$$u+iv= x+iy +\frac 1{x+iy}= 
x+iy +\frac{x-iy}{r^2}$$

Equate the real and imaginary parts, respectively, to get

$$x=\frac{r^2 u}{r^2+1},\>\>\>\>\>y=\frac{r^2 v}{r^2-1}$$

and substitute above into $x^2+y^2=r^2$ to obtain

$$\frac{r^2u^2}{{(r^2+1)^2}}+ \frac{r^2v^2}{{(r^2-1)^2}}=1$$

which represents an ellipse centered at origin, with the major and the minor axes of $\frac{r^2+1}{r}$ and $\frac{r^2-1}{r}$, respectively.

Answer (score 1):

Slightly differently:

Given that $|z|=r, (r \ne 1)$, the $$w=u+iv=z+1/z=z+\bar z/(z\bar z)=z +\bar z/r^2=x(1+1/r^2)+iy(1-1/r^2)$$
$$\implies x=u/(1+1/r^2), y=v/(1-1/r^2)$$
As $x^2+y^2=r^2$ we get ellipse in $(u,v)$ space as
$$\frac{u^2}{(r^2+1)^2}+\frac{v^2}{(r^2-1)^2}=1, r\ne 1.$$